# Display problems after a fresh install of Magento 2.0.2

Tags: magento, magento-2.0

I am having some trouble with the display on both the front and back end after installing Magento 2.0.2. This is a fresh install.

I can't see any error codes. I have looked through and tried using information for similar issues on previous posts, but none are using Magento 2.0.2 and i cannot figure out how to fix the problems. I think it could be an apache re write issue, but perhaps someone might have more insight into what could be causing the display problems.

I have put a couple of screen grabs below, any help is greatly appreciated.

[Front End](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHOZM.png)

[Back End](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0iHs.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

It's a deploy issue of Magento 2. Run this command on your magento directory:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

You can see more at [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your Magento instance runs in the "*developer*" mode please validate this conditions:

- "*mode_rewrite*" is enabled on your web server;
- `.htaccess` files are allowed by web server configuration (*AllowOverride All*);
- your web server has write access to `./pub` & `./var` folders under your Magento 2 instance;